# Is casting a pointer/address of object type T to void* and then back to the original type T always safe?

Tags: c, void-pointers, memory-alignment, iso

A lot of books say that it is safe and the ISO goes "A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any incomplete or object
type. A pointer to any incomplete or object type may be converted to a pointer to void
and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer."

I've prepared a C program with 5 cases where I used a lot of `void*` conversions back and forth on purpose.

The code works fine and here are my questions:

1. Is it always safe to cast back and forth void pointers even if
   the void pointer is assigned temporarily another object address that differs from
   the original one ?
2. Is casting to `void*` always safe? Are there some caveats we should
   be aware of?
3. Some C references suggest that "The programmer should always use explicit casts when converting between pointer types". So does it mean that if I have `int a = 10;` I should do something like `void* p = (void*)&a;` instead of `void* p = &a;`?
4. Is it always correct to assign a pointer of type `T` the name of
   an array of the same type (since arrays name are treated as pointers)?
   I mean something like `int arr[] = {1, 2, 3}` and `int* p = arr`).

Here is my C program with the 5 cases I've mentioned:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fx( void* p ){
    
    void* p1 = p;
    p = malloc((sizeof(int))*3);
    void* p2 = p;
    int* p3 = (int*)p1;
    int* p4 = (int*)p2;

    p4[0] = 10;
    p4[1] = 20;
    p4[2] = 30;

    p3[0] = p4[0];
    p3[1] = p4[1];
    p3[2] = p4[2];

    free(p2);

}

struct Test{

        int a;
        char b;
    };


void* fx2( void* p ){

    int a = 10;
    void* p1 = (void*)&a;
    p1 = p;
    struct Test* p2 = (struct Test*)p1;
    (*p2).a = 100;
    (*p2).b = 'G';

    (*(p2+1)).a = 200;
    (*(p2+1)).b = 'H';

    (*(p2+2)).a = 300;
    (*(p2+2)).b = 'I';

    void* p3 = (void*)p2;
    return p3;

}


int main(){
   
    
    /* case 1  */

    int a = 10;
    int b = 30;
    void* pv = (void*)&a;
    void* pv2 = (void*)&b;
    pv2 = pv;
    int* pa = (int*)pv2;
    *pa = 50;

    /* at the end of case 1 a is 50 */

    //case 2

    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    void* p = (void*)arr;
    fx(p);
    int* p1 = (int*)p;
    
    /* at the end of case 2 
    arr[0] is 10, arr[1] is 20, arr[2] is 30*/
    
    //case 3

    struct Test t1;
    t1.a = 10;
    t1.b = 'A';
    struct Test t2;
    t2.a = 20;
    t2.b = 'B';
    struct Test t3;
    t3.a = 30;
    t3.b = 'C';

    struct Test arrt[] = {t1, t2, t3 };
    void* pvtest = (void*)arrt;
    pvtest = fx2(pvtest);
    struct Test* ptest = (struct Test*)pvtest;

    /* at the end of case 3 (arrt[0]).a is 100,
     (arrt[0]).b is G, (arrt[1]).a is 200, 
     (arrt[1]).b is H,(arrt[2]).a is 300,
     (arrt[2]).b is I
      */


     /* case 4 */

     int x = 10;
     int* px = &x;
     int** pxx = &px;
     void* pxxv = (void*)pxx;
     void** pxxv2 = (void*)pxx;

     /* 
     Are void* pxxv = (void*)pxx; and 
     void** pxxv2 = (void*)pxx; equivalent ? 
     */

    /*case 5 */

    int arrx[] = { 1, 2, 3};
    int* parrx = arrx;
    *parrx = 10;
    *(parrx+1) = 20;
    void* pvarrx = (void*)parrx;
    int* parrx2 = (int*)pvarrx;
    *(parrx2+2) = 30;

    /*   
     at the end of case 5 arrx[0] is 10, arrx[1] is 20
     and arrx[2] is 30
    */


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is confusing in the quote of the C Standard?

Comment: OT: `(*p2).a = 100` -> `p2->a = 100`. Both forms are equivalent, but nobody uses the first form.

Comment: `void* p = (void*)&a`  instead of `void* p = &a` : the explicit `(void*)` cast is useless.

Comment: @alessiosolari If nothing confuses you in the quote then your question does not make sense.

Comment: For case 4, `void** pxxv2 = (void*)pxx;` is converting from `int **` to `void *` and then to `void **`. This is OK as long as the resulting `void **` pointer stored in `pxxv2` is correctly aligned for an object of type `void *`, but it would not be OK to then dereference `pxxv2` because the object it is pointing to has a different type `int *`. So I would say that `void *pxxv = (void *)pxx;` and `void **pxxv2 = (void *)pxx;` are not equivalent.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, the `*p2` in `(*p2).a = 100` sets an effective type of an object pointed by `p2` to `struct Test`. Afaik it is not guaranteed for `->` operator.

Comment: @tstanisl `(*x).y` is equivalent to `x->y` by definition.

Comment: @tstanisl I'm curious as to what you feel the difference is between `(*x).y` and `x->y`. I do see the former used but find it semantically obnoxious.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, the problem is that there is no such definition in C standard. There is one for `[]` but not for `->`.

Comment: @tstanisl could you provide evidence ?

Answer (score 3):

> Is casting a pointer/address of object type T to void* and then back to the original type T always safe?

Yes it is always safe.

Yet converting from *object pointer*, to `void *`, back to the same type of object pointer may result in a pointer of a different bit pattern.  The original pointer and the round-tripped pointer will still *equate* (`==`) though.

---

> Is it always safe to cast back and forth void pointers even if the void pointer is assigned temporarily another object address that differs from the original one ?

"cast back and forth void pointers" is unclear.  Going from `void *` to `void *` does not involve a cast.

> Is casting to void* always safe? Are there some caveats we should be aware of?

Safe for *object* pointers, not certainly *function* pointers.

> Some C references suggest that "The programmer should always use explicit casts when converting between pointer types". So does it mean that if I have int a = 10; I should do something like `void* p = (void*)&a;` instead of `void* p = &a;`?

No.  Using casts between `void *` and an object pointer is not needed.  You should follow your groups' coding standard for such style issues.  I do not recommend unneeded casts.

> Is it always correct to assign a pointer of type T the name of an array of the same type (since arrays name are treated as pointers)? I mean something like `int arr[] = {1, 2, 3}` and `int* p = arr`).

"arrays name are treated as pointers" is a false premise.  Arrays are not pointers. Pointer are not arrays.

`int arr[] = {1, 2, 3}` is not an *assignment*.  It is an *initialization*.

In the case of `int* p = arr`,  array `arr` is converted to the type and address of the first element of the array, so like `int* p = &arr[0];`, which is certainly OK.

Comment: So chux, is it also true when the void pointer is temporarily assigned an address of an object that differs from the original one ?

Comment: @alessiosolari The conversion of a `void *` to/from an _object_ pointer may result in a pointer the same size and same bit pattern.  The conversion may result in a pointer of a different size and bit pattern.  Yet in both cases the 2 pointers are still _equal_.

Comment: chux, when I said "cast back and forth void pointers" maybe I was a bit incorrect. What I meant is basically what I did in the main function in the case 1 where pv2 had the address of b but then it was made to point to a and casted to int*. Are those operations correct ?

Comment: @alessiosolari Case 1 is OK `at the end of case 1 a is 50` is true with no UB.

Comment: is case 4 correct ?

Comment: @alessiosolari Case 4 is only correct if `int *` and `void *` have the same alignment requirement. Dereferencing `pxxv2` would not be correct even if it is correctly aligned.

Comment: Ian Abbott, so if I have int a = 10; int* pa = &a, int** ppa = &pa; Is it correct to do something like void* pv = (void*)&ppa; and then do int** p3 = (int*)pv; ?